# How to only allow/validate a string starting with certain characters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I'm trying to figure out how to validate Canadian Postal codes right now before they are stored in the rails database. But I don't want to do it with regex in my validation. I want to store an existing postal code starting with certain characters and then not caring whatever comes after, as long as the initial characters match with what I have set.

For example, if someone enters `V7C2X2`, `V7C1X1` or `V7B1X1`, it should accept it because it starts with the characters `V7C` or `V7B`. It should reject any entry that does not start with `V7C` or `V7B`.

I have this right now:

```
class Postal < ApplicationRecord
  validates_inclusion_of :postalcode, :in => ["V7C", "V7B"]
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a custom validator.

```
class Postal < ApplicationRecord
  validate :code_includes

  private

  def code_includes
    ["V7C","V7B"].include? postalcode
  end
end
```

That will just check that postalcode has either of those two strings anywhere as a substring.

To check that postalcode starts with one of those two you could do

```
class Postal < ApplicationRecord
  validate :code_starts_with

  private

  def code_starts_with
    postalcode.start_with?("V7C","V7B")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out validates_format_of.  You can do the following:

```
validates_format_of :postalcode, with: /^(V7B|V7C)/
```

Also takes without: /**/